# Questionnaire creation using Asp .net MVC – Admin module

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am working in an Admin module where I have a page called forumCreation. In that, Admin can create an “N” number of questions and each “N” number of questions can have an “N” no of answers. I can say it as endless.

For an Example:
Question no: 1
 -     Where are you from?
Answer: 
 - within US
 - outside US
Question no:2
 - Where are you from within US?
Answer 
 - User has to choose an option (State) from the dropdown

So, this module has an option to configure endless question and answers. Also, admin has rights to edit or delete an already configured forumlist. Could any one suggest me how to do using Asp.net MVC 4 with strongly typed and entity framework?

Comment: I guess starting with some tutorials on MVC would be a good first step.  We can definitely help with specific questions about the code you write, any errors or unexpected behavior you encounter, etc.  But we can't provide you with end-to-end guidance for your entire project.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to post an array of json.

A sample of how to post using ajax:

```
$.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: url,
            data: obj,
            //dataType: 'json',
            success: function (responseData, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                console.log('ok');
            },
            error: function (responseData, textStatus, errorThrown) {

                console.log('POST failed.');
                console.log(textStatus);
                console.log(errorThrown);
                console.log(responseData);
            }
        });
```

here's a full sample:

http://blog.dontpaniclabs.com/post/2013/02/27/Posting-JSON-Data-to-an-MVC-Controller-via-Ajax

posting an array using ajax:

http://kwilson.me.uk/blog/post-an-array-of-objects-to-webapi-using-jquery/

Comment: Thanks mate. It can be considered but I am looking to go for Model binding, since I need to capture the log (History) using Entity Framework.

Comment: you'll use model binding. But there's no way to add one more answer dynamically without some programming on the client side.